# Camera preview with a transparent image above

Tags: android, camera, preview

I would like to see an image on top of Camera SurfaceView\preview.
How do I do that? Any examples?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A great example can be found in [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library, [Barcode Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android) application.

What they do is they use `FrameLayout` for `SurfaceView` and their custom `ViewfinderView` so that both `SurfaceView` and `ViewfinderView` are covering full screen:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_view"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
      android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/transparent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note the `fill_parent` values in `layout_height` and `layout_width` for both views.

And then they draw custom things in [`ViewfinderView.onDraw()`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java#76) method, just on top of what is being displayed by camera preview.

If you don't want to draw anything, but just use predefined image, then use `ImageView` instead of `ViewfinderView`. You might consider calling `setAlpha` method to make your image transparent (if drawable wasn't already transparent by itself).

---

Here is a screenshot from Barcode Scanner:

[image]