# App idea issue: Android camera face detection with adding pictures on face

Tags: android

I have been searching about camera face detection. I did find out solution for api 14 but I have task to make app for api 8 with resizing layer with picture to size of face- is it possible on api 8?

Comment: `FaceDetector` has been added to Android since API Lv.1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html So it's totally possible to do face detection on any Android devices on the market. What did you mean by saying "resizing layer w/ picture to size of face"?

Comment: Face Detector identifies the faces of people in a Bitmap graphic object, so do we count running camera ? 
I need to add layer with picture(like funny  hat, glasses, nose) so that you see yourself with funny items in your face during camera is turned on- do you have some examples?

Comment: its completely doable. You can start some google search `site:stackoverflow.com adding button on camera viewfinder android` and here's solved question regarding to how to put objects on camera viewfinder(preview) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181165/camera-preview-with-a-transparent-image-above

Comment: @ŁukaszSzpyrka you find any solution than please help me??

Comment: sorry @VishalPatoliyaツ I don't remember the solution. But the app is running till this day. BTW. I'm iOS developer since then haha:)

Comment: @ŁukaszSzpyrka hahahaha